# Stored Procedure - Exclude where conditions in a separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck in a situation and I need your help.

I have a stored procedure with a select statement which has some joins and many where condition foreach product settings. The structure looks like below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID
WHERE T1.STATUS = 'UnResolved'
AND
(
   T1.COL1 NOT IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')

   AND (T1.Product != 'TEST1' OR T2.COL2 = 'V2' OR T3.COL3 = 'V3') 
   AND (T1.Product != 'TEST2' OR T2.COL2 = 'V2' OR T3.COL3 = 'V3') 

   AND (T1.Product != 'TEST3' OR T2.COL4 = 'V4' OR T3.COL5 = 'V5') 
   AND (T1.Product != 'TEST4' OR T2.COL4 = 'V4' OR T3.COL5 = 'V5') 
)
```

There are only two fixed possible settings for any product.

Setting 1 : OR T2.COL2 = 'V2' OR T3.COL3 = 'V3'

Setting 2 : OR T2.COL4 = 'V4' OR T3.COL5 = 'V5'

Every time a new product comes in we need to add a new where condition with its respective setting.

Now for the new requirement, we need to automate this process by using any config table.

Can someone please suggest below things

@. structure of table

@. modify select query such that we do not need to modify the existing conditions

@. we also need to take care that existing logic does not break

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things - especially around stored procedures - are highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1):

Create table `product_config` with columns `product, type, col1, col2`. `product` should be
foreign key to `T1.product`.

For every product create row in it. `type` specifies which of `col2, col3` or `col4, col5` is used.

```
product    type 
TEST1       1 
TEST2       1
TEST3       2
TEST4       2
```

Then query will look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN PRODUCT_CONFIG C ON (T1.PRODUCT = C.PRODUCT)
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID
WHERE T1.STATUS = 'UnResolved'
AND
(
  T1.COL1 NOT IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')

  AND (C.TYPE != 1 OR T2.COL2 = 'V2' OR T3.COL3 = 'V3')
  AND (C.TYPE != 2 OR T2.COL4 = 'V4' OR T3.COL5 = 'V5')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1 solution I have used before is to create a lookup table having your input parameters and the where condition used. For example you could create a table with the following columns:

1. PRODUCT_NAME
2. PRODUCT_TYPE
3. PRODUCT_PRICE
4. WHERE_CLAUSE

Using this fire a lookup query, say you have the name, type & price:

```
SELECT WHERE_CLAUSE FROM PRODUCT_CRITERIA WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = :PRODUCT_NAME AND  PRODUCT_TYPE = :PRODUCT_TYPE AND PRODUCT_PRICE = :PRODUCT_PRICE
```

In oracle the WHERE_CLAUSE can be used to execute a dynamic query using 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'